# How does SSO (Single Sign On) work

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm trying to wrap my head around SSO.  It's my understanding that SSO allows you to login once and get access to multiple apps (if you have rights).  So, I log into App A.  I establish a token.  How does that token become available to App B so I do not have to login to App B again (assuming user has rights to A and B)?  My Apps are AngularJs apps.  I access .Net WebAPis for data.

I can see if I login to App A and retrieve a token then launch App B from App A by passing the token to App B.  This way App B has the token and can send to server to make sure user has access to B.  However, if user opens a browser directly and goes to App B, then how does their session get established with existing token?

If the answer is there's session state on the back-end server, then how does session state match the user logged in App A with the new request for App B?

Thanks.

Comment: This is literally the first hit for your title in Google: https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/23/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/

Comment: @thebjorn I read that first hit link about 20 times and I still can't understand through what exactly does the server realize that the browser is already logged in, probably because that text is meant for the general public not a programmer, while the answer below made it immediately obvious that it's thanks to `HMTL5 Local Storage` that it all works, but does this also mean that JS is absolutely required to use SSO?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen yoou don't need local storage/JS. The auth/sso/login-server logs a user in the normal way (using sessions/cookies/even local storage, as long as it can tell that the user is logged in the next time he visits the loginserver). When a client-server needs the user to log in before showing a page, it doesn't present a login form, but redirects to the loginserver. Since the loginserver knows that the user is logged in it sends back a message saying "this is user 123", and since the client server trusts the loginserver it logs user 123 in locally without requiring a password.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen ..obviously the message from the loginserver needs to be communicated securely. One way is to encrypt the message and send it as a get parameter in a redirect.. (it's simple, but discloses the message to the user). Or we just send a "token", a unique random value. The client server then needs to contact the loginserver directly (i.e. server-to-server outside of the browser) and say "I have this token, can you give me data?"  If the loginserver recognizes the token it sends back "this is user 123", and the client server logs the user in without a password.

Comment: @thebjorn So if he is not logged in on the app, it will redirect and automatically login the user on the loginserver. I really appreciate your feedback, knowing that JS is not mandatory changes my understanding once again (really, all the explanations are really confusing unless you already understand the concept).

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Exactly :-) The app redirects any non-logged-in user, and logs in (without password) all users coming from the loginserver -- that is all. The loginserver immediately redirects users back whence they came (if they're already logged in), or presents a login-screen first if they're not logged in (that's all). I agree that the vast majority of explanations are much to focused on minutia around securing the messages sent during the redirects. SSO is conceptually pretty simple, but I had to implement a homegrown version of it to think so (and to appreciate the minutia ;-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Well, there are certainly many ways to achieve it, and it can be tricky. I can give you one solution as an example:

Consider two apps on different subdomains:

```
The Fine Corinthian Turkey Shop (turkey.example.com)
Rent a Baboon (monkey.example.com)
```

These two web apps want to share signon, and arrange for a third hosted website for their single sign-on:

```
sso.example.com
```

Then the flow is:

1. Frank visits http://turkey.example.com/orders/12
2. Turkey redirects to https://sso.example.com/login
3. SSO presents user with login form, validates and issues token
4. The token is saved in a cookie on SSO.
5. User is now validated on SSO, but needs to get the token back to turkey.
6. SSO stores a combination of (Guid, Token, Expiry) on the server, where Guid is a random guid and Expiry is something like 30 seconds.
7. SSO sets a secure cookie on *.example.com containing the Guid
8. SSO redirects back to http://turkey.example.com/orders/12
9. Turkey can now retrieve the ticket from the cookie
10. Turkey calls SSO server and exchanges the ticket for the token.
11. Turkey stores token in the browser (typically a cookie)

Now let's imagine that Frank wants some nice juicy baboons to go with that turkey:

1. Frank visits: http://monkey.example.com/order-in-bulk
2. Monkey sees that Frank has no stored token and redirects to https://sso.example.com/login
3. SSO sees that Frank is already logged in as he has a stored token.
4. SSO stores a new (Guid, token, expiry) triple on the server
5. Process is identical to the initial login the rest of the way

Comment: Thank you for the colorful example.  This is helpful.  So, SSO sees that Frank is already logged in as he has a stored token (#3 from baboons above).  This is the piece that puzzles me.  How does SSO see that Frank is already logged in?  Monkey has no knowledge of the token from Turkey.  What does SSO use to know that the request from monkey is from Frank?

Comment: When the user signs in at SSO, the refresh/access tokens are stored in localStorage. This will be available for subsequent visits to SSO.

Comment: "Frank wants some nice juicy baboons to go with that turkey"  - Frank should remember he's only renting them :)

Comment: What does SSO use to know that the request from monkey is from Frank?   How does SSO see that Frank is already logged in? It uses a browser cookie - see my answer. The requests to SSO are all from the browser user agent, not from the App.

Comment: @iandayman: Yeah, well - Frank is not a nice person :D For the second part, yes. The 'real' token is stored in HTML5 Local Storage in my case, but a cookie would also suffice, unless to token is larger than 4kB.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen : I don't think Oauth access/refresh tokens have anything to do with SSO though. They do allow an application to access a user's data long-term (but that's whether that user is signed-in or signed-out). Browser cookies between a user and Identity server are the only way I've seen SSO done.

Comment: @iandayman: True, but since Tom Shrek mentioned tokens in his question and it is tagged OAuth2, I assume JWT.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen, While this explains the SSO flow well, Local Storage and even Session Storage are only meant for nonsensitive information, which auth tokens are not.

Comment: @PhillipMartin: Interesting point. I hadn't really considered security when writing this. Http only cookie is a better choice, I agree. I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen, to be fair, after further research I found that stackoverflow wrote a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) about how they do SSO and they use local storage. Although, it looks like they put a lot of thought into why that was acceptable for them.

Comment: The flow can be achieved using OIDC.

Answer (score 5):

> However, if user opens a browser directly and goes to App B, then how
>   does their session get established with existing token?
>
> If the answer is there's session state on the back-end server, then
>   how does session state match the user logged in App A with the new
>   request for App B?

I would say it's more about cookies and redirects than it is tokens. Tokens are generated once a user's identity is established.

So when you hit App B via your browser, App B redirects your user-agent to the Auth Server (which may in turn redirect you to a SSO site).

The thing to note is that the SSO login request is actually an HTTP request between your browser and the SSO server.

So the SSO cookie is already there - because earlier, App A would have also redirected your user-agent to the Auth / SSO server where the login was performed. The SSO server could then persist a cookie between you and it.

> I can see if I login to App A and retrieve a token then launch App B
>   from App A by passing the token to App B.

I'm not sure I understand about App A passing its token to App B. Usually Apps (Oauth 2.0 clients) would not share tokens. App B should make its own request to the Auth server which (if the user is signed in) may skip the login part but would then need to verify that :

1. App B has rights to the scopes requested and that
2. the signed-in user has granted access to those scopes.

If the user is logged in and has previously approved scope access then all this processing is seamless to the end user other than a bunch of redirects.

This assuming you use the Implicit grant flow (I noted that one of your apps is an angularjs app).

If you use the code, password or client-credentials Oauth2.0 grants then you may receive a refresh token after initial user login and consent.

The refresh token equates to long-term access (for that app only) without the need again for login and consent from the end-user more than once.

Answer (score 0):

`sso.example.com` stores a cookie and the same cookie help when Frank goes to `monkey.example.com`. If `sso.example.com` feels that cookie is too old then it can ask for login `auth` again.