# Is it possible to login to Office 365 web using ADAL or something without redirecting to the microsoft login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, office365, adal

I want to login to Office 365 from my .net MVC application by using my own login page without redirecting to Microsoft login.

The user writes his email and password into my login page and logs in to the application.

In my web page I have a link to Office 365 and I want the user to be with the session already started.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, also this flow is inherently less secure and not recommended. The problem with this is that any security you implement in your app is likely to be less secure than the AAD endpoint. Why risk your user's security if you don't have to. If you do decide to go this route, [using username/password flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) with Azure Active directory will allow you to get a user token without redirecting to the AAD login pages.

In particular, this redirect is specifically what enables SSO between app secured with Azure Active Directory. There is a great explanation of how SSO works in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663357/how-does-sso-single-sign-on-work), but the short version is that because cookies can't cross domains because of the single origin policy, your user needs to authenticate with login.microsoftonline.com to get a token usable for SSO.

If the user doesn't already have a cookie for Office 365, they will be redirected to the SSO endpoint so they can be issued one. Since they don't have a token for the AAD SSO server they will need to login there. Had you used the recommended flow, they would still be redirected, but the SSO endpoint will recognize that they are already logged in and issue a token for office.com without the user entering their username and password again.