# SSO - how exactly does the site performing authentication notify the site originally accessed that the user is successfully authenticated?

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm having hard time understanding SSO. Anywhere I read there are those high-level explanations of how the site that authenticates the user "passes the token" to the site that was originally accessed or that it knows that the user has already been authenticated if you access it later on. But I am still interested in the details of how those things are being accomplished.

Let's assume there are two sites, A and B, and a site X that is responsible for the authentication that A and B use.

Here are some questions that I can't find answers for:

- if I access A and are then redirected to X to input my credentials, I get authenticated and then how exactly does X let A know that I am who I am? I know there is a token involved - how is this token passed exactly? Is it passes in a query string/body/header of a request that redirects me back to site A?
- What happens after the A is notified that I have been authenticated? Does it issue me a cookie? Or am I holding this token somehow? How do A know with every subsequent request that I am who I am?
- if I got successfully authenticated accessing site A and then try to access site B, I get redirected to site X - how does the site X know that I have already been authenticated? I guess I don't pass any cookies, do I? Did I get a cookie from X when authenticating there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SSO (Single Sign On) work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663357/how-does-sso-single-sign-on-work)

Comment: Have look at this. https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I read that question before and the marked best answer.  I don't understand the step 9 - how would the Turkey site be able to read anything from a cookie set by the sso server? And what is the 6 step for?

Comment: On your server, you'll create a URL that the SSO server will redirect the user to after they are validated with some data attached as well. You would then process the data and user  as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's confusing has to do with ambiguity of term "SSO". Your questions are good but the answers would depend on how SSO is implemented, there's not a one size fits all solution. We'll answer your questions with SAML as the protocol, it's often used to implement SSO between web apps:

1. A = service provider, X = identity provider. These are "roles" a service (or an application) might play in SAML. The identity provider sends a SAML response to the service provider after the identity provider authenticates the user. A so-called binding is a set of rules in SAML spec that determines *how* the response is formatted and transmitted from identity provider to the service provider. In Web Browser SSO profile of SAML, the HTTP-POST binding mandates that the response is sent via, well, POST over HTTPS. The response contains an *assertion*, sometimes referred to as a SAML "token". The assertion is a container for statements (aka claims) made by the SAML authority (your X) with respect to authenticated entity. For example, if the identity provider authenticates user "bee", the assertion sent to the service provider may contain bee's first name, last name, user id and so on.
2. Typically you'll get a cookie. The service provider A will create a "local" (to A) session and drop a cookie with session ID (or whatever session pointer) to associate the user agent with the session. On subsequent requests to A, A knows you on the basis of the cookie which maps to a session in A. The session holds the authenticated context established, say, the user id of user "bee" that came from the SAML response in step 1.
3. Also via cookies (usually). When you're authenticated with the identity provider X, it issues its own cookie. You have one cookie for X, one for A, one for B, ...

We say "usually" because the state management (how does A or X know it's you) is not part of the SAML spec. If an identity provider comes up with an exotic state management scheme, say, fingerprinting your browser and relying on that fingerprint as your authenticated context/session id, that's still okay with SAML from a protocol perspective. Only step 1 is formally described in the protocol, steps 2 and 3 are up to the implementation. In practice, cookies have a very short list of alternatives and most apps use cookies.

Take a look at [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf), it does a good job of addressing the essence of this Q&A.